# TypeScript object - cast field as string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following TypeScript type:

```
type Colour = {
  colour: string;
  type: string;
};
```

And I have the below function:

```
const formattedKeys = (legend: { [name: string]: string }[]) => {

  return <>
         <Grid item xs={6}>{name}</Grid><Grid item xs={6}>{value}</Grid>
         </>
}
```

This function is being used by lots of others types, so I want the field's key to be dynamic.  However, I'm struggling to get the function to accept the Colour type's values. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Re *"I'm struggling to get the function to accept the Colour type's values."*: What is the symptom?

Comment: Fields's key to be dynamic ? What it means.. where is Field and name denote to which key from Colour Type? Can u add some example what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NBjd4N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Is this specific to react?  If so you should probably tag it as such. If not, please consider removing the dependency from your example.